# How to pass **kwargs along with other arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am feeding some arguments to my Python application using `argparse`

`parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`

Some arguments will become the arguments of the application, and the others will be  `**kwargs` to pass to a function inside the application.

How to tell Python that, except for some arguments in a pre-defined list, all other arguments should be combined to `**kwargs` variable.

**Update**:

```
parser = argsparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add ('--a')
parser.add ('--b')
parser.add ('--k1', default=1)
parser.add ('--k2', default=2)
parser.add ('--k4', default=1)
```

So I want to use `a` and `b` as parameters for my own application. And inside my Python application I would like to call:

`func(**kwargs)`

and

`kwargs={k1:1, k2:2, k4:4}`

The point is I don't know `**kwargs`, so the idea is that everything except for `a` and `b` will go to `**kwargs`.

Comment: Can you provide (simplified) code to demonstrate exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you're asking how to pass `**kwargs`, you build a dict or dictionary-like object, and then pass it using `**`. For example `d={'a': 1, 'b': 2}; f(x, y, **d)` Then if the function takes `**kwargs`, `kwargs` will be equal to `d`

Comment: From what you ask the answer is simply: `def name(positional, *args, keywords, with_default=42, **kwargs):`. If you want things to collect in **kwargs you simply specify it in the function declaration.

Comment: First convert your parsed arguments to a dictionary. `args = vars(parser.parse_args())` `vars` converts to a dictionary. Now you can pop those that you don't want to be your kwargs from this dictionary. `a = args.pop('a')` and `b = args.pop('b')`. After that your args is just your kwargs: a dictionary with only k1, k2, and k4 as its keys.